# Zoom with Zoomed Buttons on a UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a flat image of a map in a UIImageView and its my job to add clear buttons to some pre-defined "hot spots" that represent locations of interest on the map. However, given the size of the image on the iPhone, the hotspots they have defined are very close together and would be difficult to touch / tap.

Is there a way to zoom in on an image have those buttons scale larger so that they can be pressed more easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes add the imageview inside a scroll view,
Use this code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage"]];
    self.imageView = imageview;
    [imageview release];

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.75;
    scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    return imageView;
}
```

In the .h file you would have

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView;
```

For more info please check StackOverFlow on how to add to use UIScrollView
such as [Adding UIImageViews to UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777364/adding-uiimageviews-to-uiscrollview)

Comment: Yeah this made sense. Thanks.