# UIImageView in UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to add a **UIImageView** in the scrollview of **UIWebView**, thereby i hope i can enable pinch zoom and pan gestures which are properties of *UIWebView*.

```
[webView.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
webView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

But i can't do those Gestures.

Will this work? or should I use the default **UIGestureRecognizer**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of loading the image in an imageView and then adding the imageView to the webView, you can simply load the image directly on the webView, thereby applying all zoom,pinch and pan properties of the webView to the image.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imageName" ofType:@"jpg"];
[webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><img src=\"file://%@\"></body></html>",path] baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want zoom&pan features then just use UIScrollView with UIImageView set as contentView ([Adding UIImageViews to UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777364/adding-uiimageviews-to-uiscrollview))

Comment: I don't think UIScrollView supports zoom and pan. It would just enable you to pan or slide through images. And to enable the zoom and pan, i would need to add separate pinch and pan gesture recognizers. Am i wrong?

Comment: You actually can zoom and pan in UIScrollView. Check out this tutorial for example http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2012/07/07/tutorial-all-about-images-part-2-panning-zooming-with-uiscrollview/

Comment: right but sorry. Coz This is what i use in my code now. i'm here trying to optimize my lines of code. Thats why im searching for a workaround and  after my research i found that uiwebview supports both zoom pinch and pan without much coding.